# Not sure what's wrong with my code

Tags: php, css

I'm passing a date input using php $_GET

```
<form action="trigger_date.php" method="get">
Enter Project Turnover date (mm/dd/yy): <input type="string" name="date"> <input type="submit">
```

In the trigger_date.php takes this as

```
<?php $turnover_date = $_GET['date']; ?>
```

I do some math to compare it to today's date

```
<?php 
$project_turnover = strtotime($turnover_date);
$project_turnover = date ("m/d/y", $project_turnover);
?>
<?php 
$datetime1 = date_create($today);
$datetime2 = date_create($project_turnover);
$wks_to_turnover = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2); // taking the difference between today and project turnover date
$wks_to_turnover = $wks_to_turnover->format('%R%a'); 
$wks_to_turnover = ($wks_to_turnover/7);
$wks_to_turnover = round($wks_to_turnover,1); //with input of 5/1/14 this should be roughly 24 wks
?>
```

Here's where I'm stumped, my styling is:

```
<?php
if ($wks_to_turnover > 2) {
echo $date_green; // colors the background green 
} elseif (2 > $wks_to_turnover && $wks_to_turnover > 0) {
echo $date_yellow; // colors the background yellow
} elseif (0 >= $wks_to_turnover) { 
    echo $date_red; //colors the background red
} ?>;
```

But even if (24 > 2) it's still coloring as red

Comment: How do you know `$wks_to_turnover` is actually being calculated correctly? This part of the code seems fine (minus the lack of // in front of the last comment).

Comment: What is the value of `$wks_to_turnover`? `var_dump($wks_to_turnover);`

Comment: when i manually input "5/1/14" instead of using the $_GET method, the styling works fine. Also I'm outputting the value of `$wks_to_turnover` in a table as a sanity check for me so

Comment: `$turnover_date` and `$project_turnover` ?? I think you are getting the date in `$turnover_date` and using `$project_turnover` to calculate?

Comment: `$turnover_date` is the $_GET and `$project_turnover = date ("m/d/y", $project_turnover)`

Comment: What?? Post the whole script, complete. The chunks are making things unclear. From the looks of it, you're using an undefined variable.

Comment: With the full code flashed in your post, I am getting output as `green`. but follow @Chris's advice. date can become real mess if you are not working with it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `<input type="string" />` is not valid HTML -- you're looking for `type="text"`

`date_create` accepts several different formats of dates. The `m/d/y` format, which you're using on the input date, is bad form because it is ambiguous. Per the manual:

> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Use a standardized date format that is supported by the Date object. It may not be the cause of your issue, but it is good to be unambiguous in code.

I'm not completely sure why you turn the input into a UNIX timestamp and then back to a formatted date. You could simply use the formatted date you get from input, which appears to be in a supported format, and deal with any errors that may generate.

Finally, your math produces a negative number. **That's one reason why your logic fails to act as you expect.** You can reverse the order of arguments passed to `date_diff`, OR use `abs` to get the absolute distance between the two dates. I went with `abs`, which makes the code not care if the 2 weeks is in the past or in the future. I don't know what you're doing here -- maybe the sign matters. If so, reverse the order of arguments passed to `date_diff`

(**edit**: OP clarified `abs` would not suite his need, adjusted accordingly)

Putting it together, I would suggest something like this:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('now');
$datetime2 = date_create(
array_key_exists(
    'date',
    $_GET
    ) ? $_GET['date'] : 'invalid'
);
if (!$datetime2)
    die('invalid date');
$wks_to_turnover = date_diff($datetime2, $datetime1);
$wks_to_turnover = $wks_to_turnover->format('%R%a'); 
$wks_to_turnover = ($wks_to_turnover/7);
$wks_to_turnover = round($wks_to_turnover,1);be roughly 24 wks

if ($wks_to_turnover <= 0) {
    echo 'green';
} elseif ($wks_to_turnover < 2 && $wks_to_turnover > 0) {
    echo 'yellow';
} else {
    echo 'red';
}
```

I also adjusted the final block of `if`s -- if weeks is less than or equal to zero, green, if less than two but greater than 0 yellow, otherwise red.

Try it: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kLN5jk

**Documentation**

- `strtotime` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
- `DateTime::__construct` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php
- *Date formats* - http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php
- `date` (documents format strings) - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
- `abs` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php

Comment: Changing the date input to the `'Y-m-d'` format still doesn't make the styling work properly. and so `(24 > 2)` is still coming out red when it should be green

Comment: Side note: when using `DateTime::createFromFormat()` for comparing dates, use `UTC` timezone to avoid unexpected results caused by timezone offset and daylight saving on the default timezone.

Comment: @eg-dev-newbie just a crazy thought, have you checked `$date_green` is really green?

Comment: @eg-dev-newbie check the edit with code sample. I overlooked a glaring logical problem :)

Comment: @eg-dev-newbie Aaaand another problem with the ifs. Edited again! :P

Comment: I'm reluctant to use `abs()` as i have to show if the date has passed

Comment: @eg-dev-newbie Okay, I'll tweak it for ya :) I think I get where you're going with it: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kLN5jk -- removed abs, switched date_diff

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it return red when i pass "non numerical value" so , i tried

```
    echo (int)$wks_to_turnover;
```

and it returned '0' , the reason because the date not returned as integer yet.

a quick fix  for that using your approach

replace that line :

```
    $wks_to_turnover = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
```

with that :

```
    $wks_to_turnover = strtotime($datetime1)-strtotime($datetime2);
```

it'll return the difference in seconds , you can handle it from here